# How can I access a Collider's GameObject in script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am making a card game in Unity3d. I created cards as game objects programmatically using c#. I wanted to know how to make each objects(cards) to move on mouse button click, i tried out with Raycast  collider, but it is not working. I'm trying to access the parent GameObject that is the whole cover with the mesh and it's collider objects/components, through which I want to  access a child GameObject (just to move a position) .Is there an easy way to fix this or do you have a better way to do all of this in some other way?

Update:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {                    
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit ();
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) { 
        print (hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe post the code of the raycast collider you used ?

Comment: Yes.I used the following code  if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
                {
                    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
                       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);//**** 
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                        print(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetMouseButton(0)` should be `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`.

You try to use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`, which registers every frame the mouse is down, opposed to `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`, which only registers on the first frame the user clicks.

Example code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    print ("Pressed");
else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    print ("Released");
```

and

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    print ("Pressed");
else
    print ("Not pressed");
```

If that doesn't fix it, try replacing `if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {` with `if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000)) {`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem aswell, try this instead (Btw u can use GetMouseButtonUp aswell instead)

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
{                    
RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit ();
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) { 
    print (hit.collider.transform.gameObject.name);
}
```

}

For some way it can be accessed via Transform, it did the the trick for me!
And if you want to access the parent:

```
hit.collider.transform.parent.gameObject;
```

Now child is a bit tricky:

```
// You either access it by index number
hit.collider.transform.getChild(int index);
//Or you could access some of its component ( I prefer this method)
hit.collider.GetComponentInChildren<T>();
```

Hope I could help.
Cheers!